# Copy in adjacency model

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, adjacency-list

I need to create a sql stored procedure (Sql Server 2008 - T-SQL) which copies a node in an adjacency model.

Table can be seen as having two columns, Id and ParentId (FK to Id). Copying means that also all subordinates need to be copied.

I think that using WITH is a good start, but I'm curious if I can do this copy without using Cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem with adjacency lists is there is no general way in SQL to extract an entire sub tree, so you already have a problem of identifying all the rows you need to duplicate without resorting to a cursor.

If possible migrate your adjacency list to a nested set model which allows you to easily identify all the nodes of a subtree. However, the maintenance of a nested set model is more complex for general inserts and deletes.

EDIT: As pointed out by 'a_horse_with_no_name' there *is* a way in general SQL to process adjacency lists, recursive common table expressions.

Comment: Well, I'm actually converting my nested set model to an adjacency list because we have major performance problems when inserting nodes (for one insert on average 50.000 updates need to be done).

Comment: I can see your problem with the nested sets model with that many inserts! In which case it may well be better to read the list out of the database and handle it in some other language to generate the necessary SQL.

Comment: @Tony: there *is* a general way to extract a sub-tree in SQL, it's called recursive common table expression.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are correct, recursive CTE are available (+1 for pointing that out). I have to admit I answered the question for general SQL, not for T-SQL (I realise the question is tagged SQL Server). I just did a search for recursive CTE and the MS page has an example with an adjacency list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Comment: @Tony: What I wanted to point out is that recursive CTE *is* general SQL. It is not specific to SQL Server. All major DBMS (except MySQL) support it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, to be precise CTE came in SQL-99, so any SQL-99 compliant DBMS supports it (for example sqlite is a very common, which to me means major, db engine, but it does not support it)

Answer (score 0):

Copying a whole sub-tree is a bit of a problem because when you copy your sub-tree you are either

- denormalizing data or
- using it as a template of some sorts.

In either case you are dragging data through inconsistent state at some point - which indicates some problems with your design (for example do your records need to have multiple parents or not? if yes, then you should consider redesigning).

So, you should update the answer with a more complete example of what you are trying to do.

One solution would be to have a temporary table, selecting for the insert should not be a problem, it is just updating the referenced IDs that would be a problem.

So

1. WITH INSERT into temporary table
2. UPDATE the IDs
3. INSERT into original table
4. DELETE temp records

The procedure needs to go like this because it would be hard to change the IDs (both record IDs and ID referring to parent) in initial WITH INSERT. However it might be possible, if there was a nice function that depended only on max_id or only on old IDs.