# Recursive clone of hierarchy in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a hierarchy in table:

```
Configuration 
(
    ConfigurationId int identity primary key,
    Name nvarchar(100),
    Value nvarchar(100),
    ParentId` int foreign key referencing ConfigurationId
)
```

My task is to clone a parent with all its children, with children keeping structure. Keep in mind that `ConfigurationId` is identity and it will need to stay identity and does not necessarily start at 1. I use the same procedure as procedure i use for insert / update just with `IsClone` parameter.

Procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Configuration_Save]
    @ConfigurationId INT,
    @Name NVARCHAR(500),
    @Value NVARCHAR(500),
    @ParentId INT,
    @IsClone BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @IsClone = 0
    BEGIN
        IF (@ConfigurationId = 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [Configuration]([Name], [Value], [ParentId])
            VALUES (@Name, @Value, @ParentId)
         END
         ELSE
         BEGIN
            UPDATE [Configuration] 
            SET [Name] = @Name, 
                [Value] = @Value, 
                ParentId = @ParentId
            WHERE ConfigurationId = @ConfigurationId
        END
    END
    ELSE -- IF IsClone = 1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SourceConfigid INT
        SET @SourceConfigid = @ConfigurationId

        DECLARE @ClonedConfigId INT

        INSERT INTO [Configuration] ([Name], [Value], ParentId)
        VALUES (@Name, @Value, NULL)

        SET @ClonedConfigId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

       -- solution goes here

    END

    SELECT @ConfigurationId
END
```

Current data looks like this:

```
  ConfigurationId    Name          Value   ParentId
  -------------------------------------------------------
    1                prod          NULL      NULL
    2                Security      NULL        1
    3                SecurityKey   NULL        2
    4                Issuer        NULL        2
    5                Audience      NULL        2
    6                SyncServer    NULL        1
    7                Address       NULL        6
    8                SmtpClient    NULL        1
    9                Host          NULL        8
    10               Port          NULL        8
    11               EnableSsl     NULL        8
    12               Username      NULL        8
    13               Password      NULL        8
    14               FromEmail     NULL        8
    15               Proxy         NULL        1
    16               UseProxy      NULL       15
    17               ProxyAddress  NULL       15
    18               AddressList   NULL       15
    19               Report        NULL        1
    20               ApiUrl        NULL       19
```

I want to be able to clone the root Configuration (one with `ParentId = NULL`, in example above one with `ConfigurationId = 1` and `Name = prod`) by inserting new root configuration with a name I enter by executing stored procedure and duplicate rows to current ones with only difference being `ConfigurationId` which is identity and `ParentId` which should change according to new `ConfigurationId`s while maintaining hierarchy.

Desired data would look like this:

```
   ConfigurationId   Name          Value   ParentId
   ------------------------------------------------
    1                prod          NULL      NULL
    2                Security      NULL         1
    3                SecurityKey   NULL         2
    4                Issuer        NULL         2
    5                Audience      NULL         2
    6                SyncServer    NULL         1
    7                Address       NULL         6
    8                SmtpClient    NULL         1
    9                Host          NULL         8
    10               Port          NULL         8
    11               EnableSsl     NULL         8
    12               Username      NULL         8
    13               Password      NULL         8
    14               FromEmail     NULL         8
    15               Proxy         NULL         1
    16               UseProxy      NULL        15
    17               ProxyAddress  NULL        15
    18               AddressList   NULL        15
    19               Report        NULL         1
    20               ApiUrl        NULL        19
    21               prod2         NULL      NULL
    22               Security      NULL        21
    23               SecurityKey   NULL        22
    24               Issuer        NULL        22
    25               Audience      NULL        22
    26               SyncServer    NULL        21
    27               Address       NULL        26
    28               SmtpClient    NULL        21
    29               Host          NULL        28
    30               Port          NULL        28
    31               EnableSsl     NULL        28
    32               Username      NULL        28
    33               Password      NULL        28
    34               FromEmail     NULL        28
    35               Proxy         NULL        21
    36               UseProxy      NULL        35
    37               ProxyAddress  NULL        35
    38               AddressList   NULL        35
    39               Report        NULL        21
    40               ApiUrl        NULL        39
```

I would prefer CTE solution over nested cursors, merge and calling a procedure / function. I have tried couple of solutions listed under similar name but without success.

Edit 1:
Formatting of example data

Edit 2:
Only root nodes can be cloned meaning only entries with ParentId = NULL are options for cloning.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552101/preserve-parent-child-relationships-when-copying-hierarchical-data/28554667#28554667) answer may provide some clues as to how to clone a hierarchy.

Comment: What do you want to happen if you get passed 1 for clone and 8 as the parentid? Does it recreate the entire tree? What do you use as a parentid for the new base?

Comment: Here is a very similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266935/copy-in-adjacency-model

Comment: What I would suggest is a different data model. You have what is known as an adjacency list. Nest sets are another way of dealing with this kind of thing but they are far more flexible and easy to maintain. Converting this to the nested sets model is not trivial but not impossible either. Fortunately Jeff Moden has an article on this. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses a CTE and an `update` to make a copy of a specified hierarchy. The CTE recursively traverses from the root to the leaves and feeds an `insert` that adds "copies" of the rows. An `output` clause on the `insert` produces a table of fixup pairs containing the old and new `ConfigurationId` values for each new row. Since the `output` clause only has access to the inserted column values, we "borrow" a column (`Value`) to store the old `ConfigurationId` values. An `update` is then used to set two columns: the `ParentId` values are updated to reference the copied rows and the `Value` values are restored from the original rows.

Note that the busy work should be wrapped in a transaction. It serves to ensure that either the copy is completed or no stragglers are left behind and it needs to prevent other sessions from seeing incomplete results or changing the old `Value` data needed to complete the copy.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Configuration as Table (
  ConfigurationId Int Identity,
  Name NVarChar(100),
  Value NVarChar(100),
  ParentId Int );

insert into @Configuration ( Name, Value, ParentId ) values
  ( 'prod', NULL, NULL ),
  ( 'Security', NULL, 1 ),
  ( 'SecurityKey', NULL, 2 ),
  ( 'Issuer', NULL, 2 ),
  ( 'Audience', NULL, 2 ),
  ( 'SyncServer', NULL, 1 ),
  ( 'Address', NULL, 6 );
    --8                SmtpClient    NULL        1
    --9                Host          NULL        8
    --10               Port          NULL        8
    --11               EnableSsl     NULL        8
    --12               Username      NULL        8
    --13               Password      NULL        8
    --14               FromEmail     NULL        8
    --15               Proxy         NULL        1
    --16               UseProxy      NULL       15
    --17               ProxyAddress  NULL       15
    --18               AddressList   NULL       15
    --19               Report        NULL        1
    --20               ApiUrl        NULL       19

-- Raw sample data.
select * from @Configuration;

-- Tree sample data.
with Configuration as (
  select ConfigurationId, Name, Value, ParentId,
    Cast( Right( '0000' + Cast( ConfigurationId as NVarChar(4) ), 4 ) as NVarChar(1024) ) as Path
    from @Configuration
    where ParentId is NULL
  union all
  select CC.ConfigurationId, CC.Name, CC.Value, CC.ParentId,
    Cast( Path + N'→' + Right( '0000' + Cast( CC.ConfigurationId as NVarChar(4) ), 4 ) as NVarChar(1024) )
    from Configuration as PC inner join
      @Configuration as CC on CC.ParentId = PC.ConfigurationId )
  select *
    from Configuration
    order by Path;

-- Copy the tree.
declare @RootConfigurationId as Int = 1;
declare @Fixups as Table ( OriginalConfigurationId NVarChar(10), CopyConfigurationId Int );

-- NB: The isolation level needs to guarantee that the   Value   in the
--   source rows doesn't get changed whilst we fiddle about, nor do we want anyone else peeking.
begin transaction;

-- Copy the tree and save the new identity values.
--   We cheat and tuck the old   ConfigurationId   into the   Value   column so that the
--   output   clause can save the original and copy   ConfigurationId   values for fixup.
with Configuration as (
select ConfigurationId, Name, Value, ParentId
  from @Configuration
  where ConfigurationId = @RootConfigurationId
union all
select CC.ConfigurationId, CC.Name, CC.Value, CC.ParentId
  from Configuration as PC inner join
    @Configuration as CC on CC.ParentId = PC.ConfigurationId )
insert into @Configuration ( Name, Value, ParentId )
  output inserted.Value, inserted.ConfigurationId into @Fixups
  select Name, Cast( ConfigurationId as NVarChar(10) ), ParentId
    from Configuration as C;

-- Display the intermediate results.
select * from @Fixups;
select * from @Configuration;

-- Fix up the parentage and replace the original values.
update C
  set C.ParentId = F2.CopyConfigurationId, Value = CV.Value
  from @Configuration as C inner join -- New rows to be fixed.
    @Fixups as F on F.CopyConfigurationId = C.ConfigurationId inner join -- New row identity values.
    @Configuration as CV on CV.ConfigurationId = F.OriginalConfigurationId left outer join -- Original   Value .
    @Fixups as F2 on F2.OriginalConfigurationId = C.ParentId; -- Lookup the new   ParentId , if any, for each row.

-- Raw sample data.
select * from @Configuration;

-- Tree sample data.
with Configuration as (
  select ConfigurationId, Name, Value, ParentId,
    Cast( Right( '0000' + Cast( ConfigurationId as NVarChar(4) ), 4 ) as NVarChar(1024) ) as Path
    from @Configuration
    where ParentId is NULL
  union all
  select CC.ConfigurationId, CC.Name, CC.Value, CC.ParentId,
    Cast( Path + N'→' + Right( '0000' + Cast( CC.ConfigurationId as NVarChar(4) ), 4 ) as NVarChar(1024) )
    from Configuration as PC inner join
      @Configuration as CC on CC.ParentId = PC.ConfigurationId )
  select *
    from Configuration
    order by Path;

commit transaction;
```

Comment: I've managed to get cloning to work with minimal changes to the code you supplied. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of answers available showing how to use a recursive CTE appending some path information.  Here is a sample that needs to be adjusted for your sorting preference:

```
;with cteHierarchy  AS (
SELECT ConfigurationId, NAme, Value, ParentId,
    CAST(ConfigurationID AS varchar(255)) As HierarchyPath
FROM #Configuration WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT C.ConfigurationId, C.NAme, C.Value, C.ParentId,
    --I prefer CONCAT(), but not sure of your SQL version
    CAST(P.HierarchyPath + '.' + CAST(C.ConfigurationID AS varchar(255)) as varchar(255)) As HierarchyPath
FROM #Configuration C
JOIN cteHierarchy P ON C.ParentId = P.ConfigurationId
)

SELECT * FROM cteHierarchy Order By HierarchyPath
```